# Grails classpath

Tags: grails, classpath

I have Grails application with `web.xml(src/templates/war/web.xml)` and I need to import there `applicationContext.xml(WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml)`. Those files created by Grails and I want to use them, but I can not import applicationContext.xml to web.xml using `classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`.

I need something like this

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in my web.xml file, but Grails app classpath doesn't do this.

Comment: Could you explain why you're doing this? This seems like a strange thing to do, so if you explain what you want to achieve it'll be easier to give you the real solution.

Comment: Updated question. I use this approach cause I need to use spring security settings via xml.

Comment: It'll  be better to configure spring from Config.groovy. Kepp to generate xml for groovy. it'll be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Grails uses this approach.